# CSS - Span bg-color same height with the text

Tags: html, css

```css
p {
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<p>Hill <span class="bg-primary text-light">Side</span></p>
```

I wanted that `span` tag would have same height as the side `text` is this possible?

Comment: You can use `line-height` css style property. But you must use it as style setting of `p` tag or set your span tag's display to `block` or `inline-block` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `span.bg-primary` element to `display` as `inline-block`, then you can play with the `line-height`

```
.bg-primary {
    line-height: 43px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 60px;
}
.bg-primary {
    line-height: 43px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<p>Hill <span class="bg-primary text-light">Side</span></p>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks mate, `display: inline-block` and `line-height` do the work, thanks alot